# Frontend form with multiple posts

Tags: query-posts, forms, post-meta, wp-update-post

I've been researching frontend post-editing/creating forms, but I can't seem to find anything about having multiple forms on the same page. Please excuse my shaky understanding of POST methods.

Here is a page that does a query for all the current user's drafts of `post_type` classified. It then iterates through all the posts and creates an edit form for each.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Edit Post
 *
 * This is the default template.  It is used when a more specific template can't be found to display
 * posts.  It is unlikely that this template will ever be used, but there may be rare cases.
 */
get_header(); // Loads the header.php template.

do_action( 'before_content' ); // supreme_before_content
do_action( 'templ_before_container_breadcrumb' );

?>
<title>Edit your classifieds</title>
<section id="content" class="large-9 small-12 columns">
<?php do_action( 'open_content' ); ?>

<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user()->data;
$user_id = $user->ID;

$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'classified',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'author' => $user_id,
    // 'posts_per_page' => -1
));
echo "<h1>Edit your pending classifieds</h1><br>";
echo "<p>The following posts are your pending classifieds. After you edit a classified, it will be reviewed by our team before publishing.</p>";
?>
<div class="accordion" id="post-listing"><?php
    while ($query->have_posts()) {

        $query->the_post();

        // process form
        // if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
        if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && ! empty($_POST['post_id']) && ! empty($_POST['post_title']) && isset($_POST['postcontent']) ) {

            header('Location: /');

            $post_id = $post->ID;
            $post = array(
                'ID'             => esc_sql($post_id),
                'post_content'   => esc_sql($_POST['postcontent']),
                'post_title'     => esc_sql($_POST['post_title'])
            );
            wp_update_post($post);
            ?><pre><?php var_dump($_POST);?></div>pre><?php
            if ( isset($_POST['owner_name']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'owner_name', esc_sql($_POST['owner_name']) );
            if ( isset($_POST['phone']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'phone', true );
            if ( isset($_POST['address']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'address', true );
            if ( isset($_POST['zip_code']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'zip_code', true );
            if ( isset($_POST['add_coupon']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'add_coupon', true );
        }


        wp_nonce_field( 'update_post_'. get_the_ID(), 'update_post_nonce' );


        $fields = get_post_meta($post->ID);

        $name    = $fields["owner_name"][0];
        $phone   = $fields["phone"][0];
        $address = $fields["address"][0];
        $zip     = $fields["zip_code"][0];
        $coupon  = $fields["add_coupon"][0];
        ?>
        <div class="accordion-navigation step-wrapper">
            <a class="step-heading" href="#" onclick="toggle(edit_post_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>);"><span style="float: none;max-width: unset;text-align: left;padding-left: 26px;"><h4 style="margin: 0">Edit <?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4></span></a>
            <div class="step-post content  clearfix" id="edit_post_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" href="#">
                <form id="post" class="dropzone form_front_style" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
                    <div class="step-post content  clearfix current">
                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="post_title">Title</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="post_title" name="post_title" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>" /></div>

                        <h3>Classified Information</h3>
                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="post_title">Detail</label>
                        <span style="color: #333"><?php wp_editor( $post->post_content, 'postcontent' ); ?></span></div>

                        <h3>Seller Contact Information</h3>
                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="post_title">Owner Name</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="name" name="owner_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></div>

                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="post_title">Phone</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" /></div>

                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="post_title">Address</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="address" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" /></div>

                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="post_title">Zip</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>" /></div>

                        <h3>Coupons</h3>
                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="post_title">Add Coupon</label>
                        <input class="textfield" <?php echo $coupon ? "disabled style='background-color:#f8f8f8;color:#bdbcbc;'" : ""; ?> type="text" id="add_coupon" name="add_coupon" value="<?php echo $coupon; ?>" /></div>

                        <input class="textfield" type="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
</section>
<!-- #content -->
<?php do_action( 'after_content' );
$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );

if ( $page_for_posts != '' ) {
   apply_filters( 'supreme-post-listing-sidebar',supreme_post_listing_sidebar() 
);// load the side bar of listing page
} else {    
  get_sidebar();
}
get_footer();
?>

<script>
// open accordion when anchor link directly above is clicked
function toggle(target) {
  var   i,
  active_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("active"),
  clicked = document.getElementById(target['id']);

  if (!clicked.classList.contains("active")) {
    for (i = 0; i < active_elements.length; i++) {
        active_elements[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
  }
  clicked.classList.toggle("active");
}
</script>
```

The form seems to be working, but when a user updates the `post_title` or `post_content`, all the posts get updated with that value.

(Also, the meta fields - `phone`, `address`, etc - don't get updated at all..)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it intentional that every form element has the same ID? IDs are meant to be unique

Comment: Thanks for catching that @TomJNowell that was not intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was happening was, the global variable `$post` wasn't ending up on the POST page - so in the conditional below where the form was being processes,

```
if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && ! empty($_POST['post_id']) && ! empty($_POST['post_title']) && isset($_POST['postcontent']) ) {

        header('Location: /');

        $post_id = $post->ID;
        $post = array(
            'ID'             => esc_sql($post_id),
            'post_content'   => esc_sql($_POST['postcontent']),
            'post_title'     => esc_sql($_POST['post_title'])
        );
        wp_update_post($post);

        if ( isset($_POST['owner_name']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'owner_name', esc_sql($_POST['owner_name']) );
        if ( isset($_POST['phone']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'phone', true );
        if ( isset($_POST['address']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'address', true );
        if ( isset($_POST['zip_code']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'zip_code', true );
        if ( isset($_POST['add_coupon']) ) update_post_meta($post_id, 'add_coupon', true );
    }
```

`$post_id` evaluated to null.

My solution was to get the ID from the `$_POST` object. Here's the revised code:

```
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && ! empty($_POST['post_id']) && ! empty($_POST['post_title']) && isset($_POST['postcontent']) ) {

            header('Location: /');

            $post_id = $post->ID;
            $post = array(
                'ID'             => $_POST['post_id'], // use $_POST object instead of global $post
                'post_content'   => esc_sql($_POST['postcontent']),
                'post_title'     => esc_sql($_POST['post_title'])
            );

            wp_update_post($post);


            if ( isset($_POST['owner_name']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'owner_name', esc_sql($_POST['owner_name']) );
            if ( isset($_POST['phone']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'phone', esc_sql($_POST['phone']) );
            if ( isset($_POST['address']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'address', esc_sql($_POST['address']) );
            if ( isset($_POST['zip_code']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'zip_code', esc_sql($_POST['zip_code']) );
            if ( isset($_POST['add_coupon']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'add_coupon', esc_sql($_POST['add_coupon']) );
        }
```

And the full page for reference

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Edit Post
 *
 * This is the default template.  It is used when a more specific template can't be found to display
 * posts.  It is unlikely that this template will ever be used, but there may be rare cases.
 */
get_header(); // Loads the header.php template.

do_action( 'before_content' ); // supreme_before_content
do_action( 'templ_before_container_breadcrumb' );

?>
<title>Edit your classifieds</title>
<section id="content" class="large-9 small-12 columns">
<?php do_action( 'open_content' ); ?>

<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user()->data;
$user_id = $user->ID;

$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'classified',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'author' => $user_id,
    // 'posts_per_page' => -1
));
echo "<h1>Edit your pending classifieds</h1><br>";
echo "<p>The following posts are your pending classifieds. After you edit a classified, it will be reviewed by our team before publishing.</p>";
?>
<div class="accordion" id="post-listing"><?php
    while ($query->have_posts()) {

        $query->the_post();

        // process form
        // if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && ! empty($_POST['post_id']) && ! empty($_POST['post_title']) && isset($_POST['postcontent']) ) {

            // header('Location: /');

            $post_id = $post->ID;
            $post = array(
                'ID'             => $_POST['post_id'],
                'post_content'   => esc_sql($_POST['postcontent']),
                'post_title'     => esc_sql($_POST['post_title'])
            );

            wp_update_post($post);
            // var_dump($post);
            // var_dump($post_id);

            if ( isset($_POST['owner_name']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'owner_name', esc_sql($_POST['owner_name']) );
            if ( isset($_POST['phone']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'phone', esc_sql($_POST['phone']) );
            if ( isset($_POST['address']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'address', esc_sql($_POST['address']) );
            if ( isset($_POST['zip_code']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'zip_code', esc_sql($_POST['zip_code']) );
            if ( isset($_POST['add_coupon']) ) update_post_meta($_POST['post_id'], 'add_coupon', esc_sql($_POST['add_coupon']) );
        }


        wp_nonce_field( 'update_post_'. get_the_ID(), 'update_post_nonce' );


        $fields = get_post_meta($post->ID);

        $name    = $fields["owner_name"][0];
        $phone   = $fields["phone"][0];
        $address = $fields["address"][0];
        $zip     = $fields["zip_code"][0];
        $coupon  = $fields["add_coupon"][0];
        ?>
        <!-- <pre><?// php var_dump($post->ID);?></pre> -->
        <div class="accordion-navigation step-wrapper">
            <a class="step-heading" href="#" onclick="toggle(edit_post_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>);"><span style="float: none;max-width: unset;text-align: left;padding-left: 26px;"><h4 style="margin: 0">Edit <?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h4></span></a>
            <div class="step-post content  clearfix" id="edit_post_<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" href="#">
                <div class="step-post content  clearfix current">
                    <form id="post" class="dropzone form_front_style" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php the_ID(); ?>" />
                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="post_title">Title</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="post_title" name="post_title" value="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>" /></div>

                        <h3>Classified Information</h3>
                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="postcontent">Detail</label>
                        <span style="color: #333"><?php wp_editor( $post->post_content, 'postcontent' ); ?></span></div>

                        <h3>Seller Contact Information</h3>
                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="name">Owner Name</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="name" name="owner_name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></div>

                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="phone">Phone</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" /></div>

                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="address">Address</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="address" name="address" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" /></div>

                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="zip_code">Zip</label>
                        <input class="textfield" type="text" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>" /></div>

                        <h3>Coupons</h3>
                        <div class="form_row clearfix custom_fileds"><label class="r_lbl" for="add_coupon">Add Coupon</label>
                        <input class="textfield" <?php echo $coupon ? "disabled style='background-color:#f8f8f8;color:#bdbcbc;'" : ""; ?> type="text" id="add_coupon" name="add_coupon" value="<?php echo $coupon; ?>" /></div>

                        <input class="textfield" type="submit" id="submit" value="Update" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- #content -->
<?php do_action( 'after_content' );
$page_for_posts = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );

if ( $page_for_posts != '' ) {
    apply_filters( 'supreme-post-listing-sidebar',supreme_post_listing_sidebar() );// load the side bar of listing page
} else {    
    get_sidebar();
}
get_footer();
?>
<script>
// open accordion when anchor link directly above is clicked
function toggle(target) {
    var i,
    active_elements = document.getElementsByClassName("active"),
    clicked = document.getElementById(target['id']);

    if (!clicked.classList.contains("active")) {
        for (i = 0; i < active_elements.length; i++) {
            active_elements[i].classList.remove("active");
            console.log("removed");
        }
    }
    clicked.classList.toggle("active");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Upvoted for answering own question so others in the same situation can see what the solution was